# Pass data from activity B to A without B finishing

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a project where the user navigates from activity A to B. Some information from activity B must be send to activity A without B finishing. This should make it possible that A already starts processing the data in the background.

I have following example project:

Activity A:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var goButton: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        goButton = findViewById(R.id.goButton)

        goButton.setOnClickListener{
            startActivityForResult(Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java), 100)
        }

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == 100){
                Log.e("Picture: ", data!!.getStringExtra("picture")!!)
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Activity B:

```
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var backButton: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        backButton = findViewById(R.id.returnButton)

        backButton.setOnClickListener{
            intent.putExtra("picture", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

This works but if I remove the "finish()" line this no longer works. But I would like to send the generated UUID each time the button is pressed and not only when B is finished.

Comment: then don't use activities, use fragments

Comment: I would like to know how I can do this with activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do this as only one `Activity` may be working at the same time, all others are paused at least, probably also stopped. thus "backgrounded" `Activity` can't do anything as `Activity` is GUI - it isn't visible, so it has nothing to do. if you have to start some logic processing, nothing related with GUI, then all code should start in some background-working component, e.g. new `Thread` or simply `Service` and first `Activity` should read processed data/state of processing when it is resumed (`onResume` called)